# How to print the sum of values in a series?

Tags: python

For this function, when I try to test it out, I don't get the desired result. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Expected result:

```
>>>sumInc(3, 10, 3)-> 18
```

My result:

```
>>>sumInc(3, 10, 3) -> 135
```

My code:

```py
def sumInc(m,n,D):
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        total = total + m + (i*D)
    return total
```

Comment: What means each parameter of your `sumInc` function?

Comment: It's supposed to be like m+(m+D)+m+(m+2D) all the way up to Y where y is less than n. That's what the series is supposed to be like

Comment: Just check your `for` loop step by step.

Comment: Paste into your question the Series that you're trying to write in python

Comment: what do you mean? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making it a lot more complicated than it needs to be. If the arguments to your function are the same as the arguments to `range` (start, stop, step), then you can just pass them to the `range` you're iterating on:

```
def sumInc(m, n, D):
    total = 0
    for i in range(m, n, D):
        total = total + i
    return total
```

Of course, you don't need to write to do the sum yourself, you could just call `sum` directly on the `range` object. The whole function body could be: `return sum(range(m, n, D))`

Comment: so i goes through each value in m, n, and D?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: The expected results you show match what you'd get from adding up `3, 6, 9`. That's what you'd get from `range(3, 10, 3)`. If you don't understand the arguments to `range`, I suggest reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).